# Docker mounting rootfs caused not a directory error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying `docker-compose up -d` to my container but causes this error below:

> ERROR: for phpsample-feed_phpsample_1  Cannot start service phpsample: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused
>   \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/c/Users/testUser/Documents/phpsample-feed/src\\" to rootfs
>   \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6bf66b01f587c8826c2944b676044c6a199a0c8c2b8807adf13de0e0f8c4509/
>   merged\\" at \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6bf66b01f587c8826c2944b676044c6a199a0c8c2b8807adf13de0e0f8c4509/
>   merged/var/www/html\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory
>   onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  phpsample:
    build:
      context: .
    init: true
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:rw
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USR=user
      - DB_PW=test
      - DB_DBNAME=phpsample
      - DB_DBPREFIX=dev_
      - IS_SHORT_URL=1
      - CACHE_DRIVER=redis
      - CACHE_HOST=redis
      - CACHE_PORT=6379
      - CACHE_REDIS_DB=3
      - DEBUG=false
    restart: always
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=phpsample
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/msyql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
  redis:
    image: redis:5-buster
    init: true
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
volumes:
  db_data:
  redis_data:
```

My system and tools used:

- Windows 10 Home
- Docker Toolbox Terminal
- Kitematic
- Oracle VM

I've also tried editing my `Shared Folders` on VM by doing [this](https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/fixing-volumes-in-docker-toolbox-4ad5ace0e572). With the settings below:

Name: `c/Users` Path: `C:\Users`

Comment: Does src exist in the directory from which you are running docker-compose and is it a directory?

Comment: What if you change `./src:/var/www/html:rw` to `php_data:/var/www/html:rw`, and also add `php_data` to the `volumes:` list as well?

Comment: @wobr It is existing and it's a src file

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Your suggestion made it run, but can't be accessed through localhost:8080 and it keeps restarting when I `docker ps`.

Answer (score 0):

`src` should be a directory containing your web content, not a file.

Comment: well, it contains a string that redirects to folder that contains my web contents

Comment: You can't mount a file into a directory in docker. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: actually this setup works if I am working on a Linux environment. I am Just trying to make it work on windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose.yaml file make sure that input yaml file path is exist under volumes: